# fancybox2 problems in all but chrome

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, firefox, coffeescript, fancybox

I get no console errors for my js.  I've checked to make sure I'm not include fancybox twice per some other peoples bugs.  Nothing.  Chrome works fine but FF the images are really flakey - most of the time they pop up and instantly scale down small and with no lightbox overlay.  Basically the pop works but all of the positioning and styles are just gone.

VIEW HERE:  http://woodruff-prod.herokuapp.com/paintings/gallery

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).foundation();
  return $(".fancybox").fancybox({
    beforeShow: function() {
      $(".fancybox-skin").addClass("" + ($(this.element).data("sold")));
      console.log("Log");
      return this.title = $(this.element).data("title") + " (" + $(this.element).data("year") + ")" + " - " + $(this.element).data("dimensions");
    }
  });
});
```

ORIGINAL I DID IN COFFEESCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $(document).foundation()
  $(".fancybox").fancybox
    beforeShow: ->
      $(".fancybox-skin").addClass("#{$(@element).data("sold")}")
      @title =
        $(@element).data("title") + " (" +
        $(@element).data("year") + ")" + " - " +
        $(@element).data("dimensions")
```

MY RAILS VIEW:

```
  <div class="gallery-container">
    <% @current_published.each do |painting| %>
        <%= content_tag :div, class: "gallery-pic", role: "gallery-pic" do %>
          <a
            role=fancybox
            data-title= '<%= painting.title %>'
            data-year= '<%= painting.year %>'
            data-dimensions= '<%= painting.dimensions %>'
            data-sold= '<%= painting.sold? ? "sold" : "unsold" %>'
            rel="gallery"
            class='<%= painting.sold? ? "fancybox sold" : "fancybox unsold" %>'
            href="<%= painting.image_file_name_url(:large) %>" >
            <%= image_tag painting.image_file_name_url(:thumb), role: "painting-modal" %>
          </a>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% else %>
  <p>No Paintings</p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: it doesn't work in Chrome either (at least on my side) ... the issue is that none of the fancybox css styles are recognized (did you include the fancybox css file?)

Comment: that was it.  thank you.  Asset pipeline was messing up my css and images.